# Is it possible to get JMeter 5.4 to write to both influxdb backend listener and graphite backend listener in the same thread?

Tags: jmeter

I can get JMeter to write to Graphite or influxdb but not both within the same thread. I want to use influxdb as the backup source in case Graphite drops the data due to incorrect storage schema

Answer (score 0):

If I give the Backend Listeners a different name: i.e. influxdb Backend Listener and graphite Backend Listener, it works fine